# C# MS-Access SQL INSERT INTO Error

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I wrote a set of codes for a C# program to insert a record into the Access database.
Here's the code:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Deployment ([DateTransacted], [ProductType], Brand, Model, SerialNo, Assignment) VALUES ('May 20, 2013', 'LAPTOP', 'ASUS', 'K55V', 'ABCD1234', '10F HRD',)", cnn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cnn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cnn.Close();
```

The program is executable. However, an error popped up saying:

> Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement

The [DateTransacted] is a string type. What should I do?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Soner

Comment: Is there any reason to use string to store DateTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this unnecessary comma;

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Deployment ([DateTransacted], [ProductType], Brand, Model, SerialNo, Assignment) VALUES ('May 20, 2013', 'LAPTOP', 'ASUS', 'K55V', 'ABCD1234', '10F HRD',)", cnn);
                                                                                                                                                                                                        ^^ Delete it
```

You can use this;

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Deployment(DateTransacted, ProductType, Brand, Model, SerialNo, Assignment)
VALUES ('May 20, 2013', 'LAPTOP', 'ASUS', 'K55V', 'ABCD1234', '10FHRD')", cnn);
```

By the way, `DateTransacted` and `ProductType` are not reserved words on ms access. You don't need to use them with square brackets.

And more important, you should always use *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)*. This kind of code are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

Comment: @JamesKevinDeJesus You are welcome `;)` Read 
[How to Say Thanks in an Answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/)

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra comma `,` at the end of your insert statement.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Deployment
([DateTransacted], [ProductType], Brand, Model, SerialNo, Assignment)
VALUES ('May 20, 2013', 'LAPTOP', 'ASUS', 'K55V', 'ABCD1234', '10F
HRD',)", cnn);
   ^^^
```

Remove that and you will be good to go, Your statement Should be

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Deployment
([DateTransacted], [ProductType], Brand, Model, SerialNo, Assignment)
VALUES ('May 20, 2013', 'LAPTOP', 'ASUS', 'K55V', 'ABCD1234', '10F
HRD')", cnn);
```

If you are using strinc concatenation to form the query then consider using [parameterized query](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access), that will also save you from [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Thank you, Habib. I didn't see that because I got desperate when the program keeps showing errors.

Answer (score 2):

remove the `,` at the end of sql statement

```
"INSERT INTO Deployment ([DateTransacted], [ProductType], Brand, Model, SerialNo, Assignment) VALUES ('May 20, 2013', 'LAPTOP', 'ASUS', 'K55V', 'ABCD1234', '10F HRD')"
```

Better to use Parameters and using blocks  as below,

```
using(var con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = 
    new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Deployment ([DateTransacted], [ProductType], Brand, Model, SerialNo, Assignment) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", con))
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "May 20, 2013"); // if you have date time column give DateTime object as value
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", "LAPTOP");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", "ASUS");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", "K55V");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", "ABCD1234");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", "10F HRD");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Parametrized Query to avoid all syntax faults and avoid SQL injections.

**Code should be:**

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Deployment VALUES (@dateOfTran, @prodType, @Brand, @Model, @serNum, @assignment)", cnn); 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
cnn.Open(); 
cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfTran",'May 20, 2013');
cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("@prodType",'LAPTOP');
.
.
.
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
cnn.Close();
```

Comment: I'd like to try the codes in another project. Thanks for your help, Freelancer.